# Android: Starting multiple pending intents as same time using Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

in my application i want to set multiple reminders. The code i used is following,

```
    intnt = new Intent(appConxt, RempopActivity.class);
    intnt.putExtra("evinfo", evtime + " " + rem.getname()
            + "\n will start in " + remtime + " minutes");
    intnt.putExtra("evid", remcon.getEvid());
    intnt.putExtra("remId", remcon.getRemid());
    intnt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(appConxt, remcon.getRemid(), intnt,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am = (AlarmManager) appConxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime() - (remtime * 60000),
            pendingIntent);
```

My question is even after having different **requestCode**, if more than one pending intent starting at same time only one pending intent is displayed other pending intents wont come up. How can i get all the pending intents.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake with above code, since i had RempopActivity as "SingleInstance" in Manifest file, according to activity Launch mode for SingleInstance no more task is added on top of this activity. For above code to work fine use Launch Mode as "standard".